# Which library can replace causal_conv1d in machine learning programming?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Recently, I have been using the library causal_conv1d for machine learning programming, and causal_conv1d is a part of the mamba_ssm library. However, I can only run these libraries on NVIDIA GPUs. I am using a MAC machine with an M-series chip (M2 PRO). How can I use the causal_conv1d library on my MAC machine or is there any alternative library available?

I've tried installing PyTorch with the MPS version, but it seems like the causal_conv1d library directly requires support for nvcc and CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

The `causal_conv1d` implementation for Mamba comes from [this repo](https://github.com/Dao-AILab/causal-conv1d/tree/main), which implements the `causal_conv1d` operation using custom cuda kernels.

Cuda kernels can't run on Mac silicon. To run `causal_conv1d` on Mac silicon, you would need to rewrite the kernels in Metal or another Mac compatible framework.

To my knowledge a Mac compatible version does not currently exist.